# Secuencia de cuerpo de solicitud agotado en safari ios

Tags: c#, ios, windows, asp, autenticación

Estoy trabajando en un sistema desarrollado en [asp](/questions/tagged/asp), la cual tiene la autenticación de [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), estoy implementando un control de "*FileUpload*", el cual funciona correctamente en navegadores de **Escritorio**, pero cuando hago la prueba en **iPad** el problema se da:

> "Secuencia de cuerpo de solicitud agotado"

He leído en otros post que el problema se debe a la autenticación de Windows, pero desactivarlo no es una opción para el cliente.

Comment: Safari no tiene soporte para Windows Authentication, en iPad solo te funcionará en el caso de que uses Chrome.

Comment: Les es posible realizar lo que indica @JavierRos dentro del cliente. NTLM, el protocolo de autenticación de Windows, es propietario y por lo visto en Safari suele ser un problema (anda bien en una versión y mal a la siguiente, por ejemplo).

Comment: Hace algún tiempo yo tuve un problema parecido y lo solucioné con este post de satckoverflow en inglés [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613196/ajax-post-request-only-works-once-in-safari-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613196/ajax-post-request-only-works-once-in-safari-5) y este otro [http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/535/Safari-Ajax-y-autenticacion-Windows-No-se-envian-lo-datos-del-POST.aspx](http://www.devjoker.com/contenidos/catss/535/Safari-Ajax-y-autenticacion-Windows-No-se-envian-lo-datos-del-POST.aspx) tal vez te sirve de algo revisalo... solo que usa AJAX Espero mi re

Comment: [Aquí descartan esa posibilidad](https://forums.asp.net/t/1610952.aspx?asp+net+upload+file+not+working+for+IPad+IPhone) en un escenario parecido al tuyo.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lleva bastante tiempo la pregunta, pero contesto por si a alguien le puede servir de ayuda.

Se podría utilizar la propiedad:

```
Environment.OSVersion
```

Que devuelve el sistema utilizado y a partir de ahí ejecutar la aplicación con o sin autenticación.

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que la llamada falla es debido a un error en Safari cuando se trabaja con la autenticación de Windows en IIS. 
**PASOS**

1. Clic derecho en Autenticación de Windows.
2. Elija providers.
3. Elimine Negotiate,

Esto te va a permitir trabajar con NTLM, sin ningún problema.

te dejo el enlace para que puedas solventar tus dudas:[click](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/cc339532(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)